# stop links opening depending on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to prevent all my links with the `class="blocker"` attribute opening on small screens (i.e. iPhone). At the moment the images are set to open with prettyPhoto, which I wish to keep on larger screens. I have trawled through here to find sections of javascript to help (I am novice with javascript) and came up with the `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` as well as the `preventDef` command. I have tried to incorporate this into an `if` statement in the `<head>` section as follows (included are the other js scripts):

```
<head>
...
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function sizeChecker(){
            if ($(window).width() || $(window).height() < 641) {
                function imgHandler() {
                    document.getElementByClass("blocker").addEventListener("click", preventDef, false);
                    }
            }
    </script>
</head>
```

in the `<body>` section the images are listed and followed by the prettyPhoto code, as follows:

```
<body>
...
    <div class="centered_image">
        <a href="image1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" class="blocker">
            <img class="img_style" src="image1.jpg" >
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="centered_image">
        <a href="image2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" class="blocker">
            <img class="img_style" src="image3.jpg" >
        </a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
        });
    </script>
...
</body>
```

My goal is to have the site use the prettyphoto plugin on anything bigger than a 640x960 screen and on all screens smaller than that, just display the images without active links. Is this actually possible?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to check both the height and width seperately, just adding a "OR" won't do:

```
$(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 641 || $(window).height() < 641) {
        $('.blocker').on('click', function() {
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

There's no need to do this on every click either, just do it on pageload, it will have the same effect. A better idea would be to do it on resize, or check the `screen` instead of `window` to get the screen size etc.

Comment: Great Thanks. Because the prettyPhoto script is separate and at the bottom of the body section I had to include the same `if` statement to turn only on the prettyPhoto script if width or height is over 960,otherwise it overrides the return false.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

first is a bit like you have tried, by measuring screen size and loading conditionally

```
        // Arbitrary width
    if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
     //do stuff for small screem
      } else {
     //do stuff for large screen
      }
```

Or you can use media queries to add an element to the body with content in it, then read the content. This is a bit more complicated to understand but in the css at breakpoints

```
@media all and (min-width: 400px) {
    body:after {
        content: 'widescreen';
        display: none;
    }
}
```

then look for that element in your javascript and do stuff with it.

```
var size = window.getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').getPropertyValue('content');
    if(size.indexOf("widescreen") !=-1 || null) {
//do something
}
```

The second example is from Jeremy Keith's blog

http://adactio.com/journal/5429/